# How do I download .sty file on Windows

Tags: packages, windows

I need to use a tex template with *.sty file. The problem is, that whenever I try to download the *.sty file, it is saved as *.sty.txt and TexStudio can't find it, as it is not .sty. There must be some straigthforward solution to this, but I just can't see it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: just right click on the file in the windows file manager and rename the file

Comment: I tried that, but it does not offer me to rewrite the .txt part

Comment: Found it! I had to tick that I want the suffixes to show. Tricky Windows. Thanks